# The verb "to be" in Modern Golic Vulcan

Tags: star-trek, languages, vulcan

does the verb "to be" exist in [Modern Golic Vulcan](http://www.omniglot.com/conscripts/vulcan.htm)? I am trying to pick up this language, and can't seem to find this verb in any of the dictionaries. If it does exist, what is it?

Comment: Depending on how the grammar works, a language doesn't necessarily need a *to be* verb.

Comment: `Pro-drop and contextually omitted copula` from the link you supplied would suggest it is at the very least often optional.

Answer (score 5):

*iti* = to be

Present form:

- itisha - is, are, am
- itishanai - is not, are not, am not

Past:

- itishi - was
- itishinai - was not

Future:

- itisho - will be
- itishonai - will not be

Resources: VegPeace.org, The Lost Memory Alpha Archives.

I does not appear in the Vulcan Language by Mark Gardner, though, but that's a good book that i recommend to any Vulcan language student.

Comment: Do you have a citation?

Comment: Resources: VegPeace.org, The Lost Memory Alpha Archives. I does not appear in the Vulcan Language by Mark Gardner, though, but that's a good book that i recommend to any Vulcan language student.

Comment: If you integrate your response to my last comment into your answer, you will get my +1. :)

Comment: I updated it. :D